# PyCharm 2.5 NameError or ImportError issues

Tags: importerror, pycharm, nameerror

Prior to the upgrade I could run my project fine.
Upgraded to PyCharm 2.5 today.

My settings and project opened up fine, no (obvious) changes, however running the project now gives me a choice of either `NameError` or `ImportError` when referencing a (custom) module, depending on whether I'm using the `import *` approach, or testing the individual import and explicity referencing the module / class. Either way it breaks!

Tested the exact same thing under ipython, which works fine.

My PYTHONPATH is okay / unchaged in the python interpreter settings.

Comment: Maybe you can share your Python interpreter settings and a sample project to reproduce it? Note that Run configuration can define its own interpreter, ensure you are using the same as for the project.